# Why the element of a Two-dimensional array in range based for loop is T* instead of T (*)[n]?

Tags: c++, arrays, types, casting

There is my code

```cpp
int array[3][4] = {
  {1, 2, 3},
  {4, 5, 6},
  {7, 8, 9}
};

for (auto line : array)
  // something
```

Why the type of `line` is `int *` instead of `int (*)[4]`?

I have looked for [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) about the range-based for loop, and I'm using C++ 11, so the corresponding source code is

```cpp
{
  auto && __range = range_expression ;
  for (auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
    range_declaration = *__begin;
  loop_statement
}
```

According to the first item of the Explanation:

> If range_expression is an expression of array type, then begin_expr is `__range`

so there is a satement `__begin = range_expression`, and it equal to `auto line = array`.
and then the type of `line` is `int (*)[4]`, but in fact it's `int *`?

Why? Could anybody help me?

Comment: The reason of this problem is I forgot to dereference to `line`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example `__begin` is of type `int(*)[4]`

`range_declaration` is the dereferenced value of `__begin`, therefore in your example `range_declaration` is of type `int*`.

In your example, the `line` variable *is* the `range_declaration`.

If we remove the syntactic sugar, your code looks like this:

```cpp
int array[3][4] = {{1, 2, 3, 0}, {4, 5, 6, 0}, {7, 8, 9, 0}};
{
  int (&__range)[3][4] = array;
  int (*__begin)[4] = __range;
  int (*__end)[4] = __range + 3L;
  for(; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
    int * line = *__begin;
  }
}
```